# Quarkus - Stream KTable updates as Server Sent Events (SSE)

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, apache-kafka-streams, server-sent-events, quarkus-reactive

The following snippet "exposes" a Kafka topic, parameterized here as `click-events`, as an HTTP SSE endpoint. I like the compact nature of this code. How do I write this code to use `click-events` topic as a `KTable` instead of a stream that it is using now?

```java
@Path("/clicks")
public class ClickStreamer {

  @Incoming("click-events")
  @Outgoing("click-sse")
  public String process(JsonObject in) {
    return in.encode();
  }

  @Inject
  @Channel("click-sse")
  Multi<String> clickSse;

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  public Multi<String> stream() {
    return clickSse;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you push the data from the KTable to a topic and consume it from there ? Afaik, a KTable doesn’t support streaming (unless you’re going to poll from it).

Comment: Pushing the KTable to a topic (`click-events`) happens upstream.

Comment: +1 to push to a separate topic. There is also an open-source project called Zilla that can expose Kafka topics as SSE streams if you want an off-the-shelf option.  https://docs.aklivity.io/zilla/latest/tutorials/sse/sse-intro.html#setup-sse-kafka-proxy